# What kind of trend, and relationship is this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I need some help with labeling the trend of this graph, and also deciding what the relationship is between the two variables (X,Y).
Here is a picture of it:
[image]

[image]

The Excel document can be downloaded here:
http://tempsend.com/5079DC65F4

Using Excels trend-line option it seems to fit either a exponential or moving average trend-line, and also to me seems like it has a horizontal asymptote. Can anyone help me with this? I am also looking at figuring out the relationship between the two variables, seeing i'm only familiar with linear relationship i have no clue.

Comment: If you need any pictures of the trend-lines excel gives me or the graph equation, just tell me if it helps with answering the question. Thanks.

Comment: This looks exponential, the vertical axis quantity roughly halves every increase of two units along the horizontal axis.

Comment: Note that a "moving average" isn't a type of function exactly, rather it just refers to a function $\hat{f(t)}$ given by averaging another function $f(t)$ over some interval in $t$, sometimes with some kind of weighting.

Comment: Could you post the points ?

Comment: Points have been added.

Comment: @Travis, could you tell if it has a vertical asymptote or not? Thanks for confirming exponential trend though!

Comment: You could try to interpolate the points and find the polynomial (if you are interested to). [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial&a=*C.interpolating+polynomial-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B1%2C+4%2C+9%2C+16%7D&f=InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data%5Cu005f%7B1%2C+4%2C+9%2C+16%7D&a=*FVarOpt-_**InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data2--) is the link to do that, you "only" need to copy your interpolation coordinates.

Comment: In the data you posted, the first column is $y$ but the second is ??. If you want me to play with your numbers, could you put them in a format such that I could edit them or send them to me by e-mail. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Ale, can i do this in Excel? And it is {{x,y},{x,y},{x,y}} correct?
So it would be: {{1.40746,2142.59},{1.175917,1495.618}.....}?

Comment: I don't think excel provides a function to interpolate data, but you can find the polynomial with wolframalpha (or with calculation, but i don't suggest it to you :P). It will be a polynomial with a very high degree. The order of input you wrote is correct. $x$ is meant the value on the $x$-axis, and $y$ the value of $f(x)$.

Comment: @Claude, do you have an email? I will send them in text form :)

Comment: EDIT: It seems i placed the wrong graph on the question, the real on is now of there. Still exponential, but would like to find out the relationship now.

Comment: Download link has been added for anyone to download which has the graph and the v and y values. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be perfectly matched using $y=a x^2$ what you can do with Excel (ask for no intercept) $a \simeq 1080$

Comment: And a is a constant i'm guessing? 
What relationship would the two variables have then?

Comment: If the function is y=ax^2, does that mean it is a power trend?

Comment: Also i believe a = 1081.6, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes and the value is correct ! You made it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: If you want to see the power trend, plot $\log(y)$ as a function of $\log(x)$ or use the logarithmic scale for the axes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help! 
So i now know it is a power trend, with function: y=ax^2

I just have to find out the relationship between the x and y axis, to see what kind of proportionality they are. Would the function suggest that it has a direct proportionality squared?

Comment: The moving average is not a model. And your curve has absolutely no horizontal asymptote.

Comment: You can indeed compare in Excel the various models supported, and try the parameters randomly, until you the the "best fit".

But it is better to imagine what the model could be, given the origin of the data. Physical experiment ? Mathematical simulation ? Economical phenomenon... ? Avoid empirism and justify your choices.

Answer (score 1):

Desmos confirms the result that you and Claude reached; your set of data is almost perfectly modeled by the function $$y=1081.6x^2$$ I tried a few other kinds of fits (exponential, higher-order polynomial, etc.), and none worked as well as the above equation, so I think that one should work pretty well for you.